# Android Custom button Padding doesn't change in pressed state

Tags: android, button, padding, android-selector

I have a custom button made by a selector in 3 states:normal,pressed and disabled.My buttons have a small layer under them to make them appear 3d.
My problem is that I want it to make the padding change (for example from 0dp on the top to 5dp from the top) when the button goes into the pressed state.I have tries several solutions but it didn't work.
Here is my code:
My selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:variablePadding="true" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_disabled" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" />
</selector>
```

Here are the states and the shadow drawable:

Shadow:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/corner_radius" />
    <solid android:color="@color/buttonshadow" />

</shape>
```

Normal :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_shadow" />

    <item >
        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners
                android:radius="11dp"
                />
            <solid
                android:color="@color/buttonColor"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

pressed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#00000000"/>
            <padding
                android:left="3dp"
                android:top="3dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:bottom="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/corner_radius" />
            <solid android:color="@color/buttonColor" />
            <padding
                android:left="3dp"
                android:top="3dp"
                android:right="0dp"
                android:bottom="0dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

My Button usage:

```
android:id="@+id/btn_gologin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello"
        style="@style/MyButton"
```

and My style :

```
<style name="MyButton" >
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/button_selector</item>
        <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
        <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>

    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you did not set the changes in the button

Assume the name of this file is  **myCustomButton.xml**

```
version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:variablePadding="true" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_disabled" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_normal" />
</selector>
```

then your  **button usage will be**

```
<android:id="@+id/btn_gologin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:background="@drawable/myCustomButton"/>
```

Comment: It is set using a style.I have added the style too just now